# Symfony2 : Hide form field with display:none

Tags: php, javascript, html, symfony

I have a serious problem about symfony2 forms, the issue that I created a very long form,so I build it with parts(fields),so In the same form sometime I sumbit this part(fields) and I hide another using `display:none` and javascript code:

```
$('#{{form.price.vars.id}}').live('change', function(){
if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
 $('#action_{{form.price.vars.id}}').show();
} else {
 $('#action_{{form.price.vars.id}}').hide();
}
});

....

    <ul id="action_{{form.price.vars.id}}" style="display:none">
<li>{{ form_row(form.price_value)  }}</li>
<li>{{ form_row(form.price_subscription)  }}{{form_row(form.price_subscription_unit)}}</li>
<li>{{ form_row(form.price_activation)  }}{{form_row(form.price_activation_unit)}}</li>
</ul>
...
```

So when I hide this fields and I click submit the form still give me that this hidden fields are empty and I must enter a value,that is means the part is hide in the client side(html code) but in backend side he still not hide?

after submitting and when I show hidden fields to see what happend I have a notification "please enter a value in emply field"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [validation groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#book-forms-validation-groups) for this.

Nothing better than a **Richard Miller** post:
[Symfony2: Using Validation Groups](http://richardmiller.co.uk/2012/06/15/symfony2-using-validation-groups/). Take a particular look at `Multiple Forms with one Entity`.